# Дана произвольная строка. В ней поменять частицу "не" на "*"

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос, ssms

Есть код , который разбивает строку на несколько

```
Declare @s varchar(100)
Declare @i int
Set @i = 1 
Set @s = 'Не Строка для тестирования'
While @i<=len(@s)
begin
print substring (@s,@i,1) -- выделение символа из строки
Set @i = @i+1 
end
```

Как мне поменять Не на * ?

Comment: Например, при помощи [функции `replace`](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_replace_function.html)

Comment: А точно MySQL? что-то синтаксис как в MS SQL (SQL Server)...

Comment: ошибся , ms sql